# Check if string is a palindrome

Tags: java, palindrome

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (line.length()/2); i++) {  \\loops from the first character until the character in the middle
    if (line.charAt(i) != line.charAt(line.length() - i)) {  \\checks if 1st character of line is not equal to the last character, and so on..
        System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
        return; \\ends program, no need to check anything else
    }
}
System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
```

I keep getting an index out of range error

Comment: Did you google the error to make an effort to understand what it is and why it's happening?

Comment: Your first step should be to look into what that means.

Comment: Do this calculations on paper (remember that indexes start from 0).

Comment: Index out of range means that you are targetting a position in the string that is not valid. charAt(-1) or charAt(n) where n is bigger or equal than the length of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index out of range error is exactly what it says.  Valid indexes in Java `String`s (also arrays or collections) range from `0` through `length() - 1`.  When you subtract `i` from `line.length()`, you can still get `line.length()`, which is out of bounds, if `i` is `0`.  This is an off-by-one error.

Subtract `1` more from the second character's index to stay in bounds.

```
if (line.charAt(i) != line.charAt(line.length() - i - 1)) {
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to check for palindromes is to invert the string and compare it with the original string.

Answer (score 3):

line.length() returns the actual length of the string, e.g.

```
'foo' -> length = 3
```

The characters have offsets 0->2

Since you're doing

```
length() - i
```

your first iteration is going to be

```
3 - 0 -> 3
```

and you end up doing

```
 string.charAt(3)
```

which doesn't exist.

Comment: If the first index was one instead of zero, my life would be much easier.

Comment: @Jack No it wouldn't. *If the first index was one instead of zero*, your life would just simply be offset by 1 :D